# upload python code on web server that runs it on on specific time intervals

Tags: python, server

Upload python code on a web server that runs it after every 4 hours. My code produces an image file . I also want to give a path to that file in an html file and display it on a web page can anyone guide through this process .The code creates/rewrites the previous image in the same directory where it runs and i would like to give a path to the image created by my python code in my html file uploaded on the same server  actually i tried using python anywhere but it does not runs my code on hourly basis which i would like to have

Comment: I have so many questions about this question... Does the code create a new image on every run or does it rewrite the previous image? What is serving the image (apache, Python, etc.)? Are the html page and the image hosted on the same machine? What have you tried?

Comment: the code rewrites the previous image. serving the image ?? the code creates /rewrites the image in the same directory where it runs and i would like to give a path to the image created by my python code in my html file actually i tried using python anywhere but it does not runs my code on hourly basis which i would like to have @nivixzixer

Comment: What OS is your web server running?

Comment: Cross-platform / HTML5 python anywhere runs on this os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP provided very little detail about the environment in which his code will run in, I have to make several assumptions. And everything must be done using Python..no cron jobs, Apache, etc.

**First**: To make your Python code run every 4 hours, use the [APS Scheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/v3.0.2) module. It makes this quite easy.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

# Put your code in this function
def make_image():
    # creates an image file with name default.jpg..


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(make_image, 'interval', hours=4)
    scheduler.start()
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))
```

---

**Second**, create a new Python file where your other Python file and image are stored and put this code in it:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 80

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

---

**Last**, be sure that both Python scripts above are running and create an HTML file that displays the image somewhere in the document.

```
<img src="http://<your-webserver-ip>/default.jpg">
```

Comment: i was actaully missing the second part!